# Equivalency of regularization among LME, Bayesian and penalized least squares

Tags: lme4-nlme, hierarchical-bayesian, regularization

Suppose that we have a linear mixed-effects (LME) model

$\boldsymbol{y}=X\boldsymbol{\beta} + Z\boldsymbol{u} + \epsilon$

where $y$ is an $n \times 1$ vector of responses and $X$ and $Z$ are design matrices for the fixed and random effects of dimensions $n × m$ and $n × q$, respectively. With the assumptions of $u \sim N(0, R)$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2I)$, $u$ can be predicted through BLUP.

I believe that $u$ can be equivalently predicted through two other approaches. One is the hierarchical Bayesian framework,

$\boldsymbol{y}|Z,\beta,Z,u \sim N(X\boldsymbol{\beta}+ Z\boldsymbol{u}, \sigma^2I)\\
u\sim N(0, R)$

And the other approach is penalized least squares (PLS),

$\underset{\beta,u}{argmin} (y-X\beta-Zu)^T(y-X\beta-Zu) + \lambda u^TR^{-1}u$,

where $R^{-1}$ and $\lambda$ are the penalty matrix and parameter, respectively.

My question is, does the equivalency among the three approaches still hold when the assumption of $\epsilon ~ N(0, \sigma^2I)$ is relaxed? For example, what happens when there is a serial correlation structure (e.g., AR(2) or ARMA(1,1)) in residuals $\epsilon$? I guess that the estimation for the serial structure can be incorporated as part of the iterative process for LME and the Bayesian framework. How about PLS?

Comment: I can't speak to the Bayesian model, but I believe the PLS is actually utilized as a computational efficient method to compute a mixed-model in many packages; so they are exactly equivalent. I think there is another important assumption in your question. You are assuming you *can* relax the normality assumption in those models. I don't believe that is true. If you have a serial correlation structure, you need to modify your model significantly.

Comment: @TannerPhillips Thanks for the comment. No, I'm not assuming I could relax the assumption of $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2I)$. Rather, I'm asking whether the equivalency holds among the 3 methods after the assumption changes from  $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2I)$ to one with a temporal structure.

Comment: Ah I see. Well it's been a while, but I know it can be proved that the LME a PLS are exactly equivalent. I'll see if I can find a source for that.

Comment: @TannerPhillips Both LME and PLS involve iterative algorithms. Why is PLS  more computationally efficient?